# set div size to percentage of header div

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, size

I want to create a div within my header div on my wordpress site. I want the size of the new div to be a % of the parent div, to occupy only the right most side of the header. The current header has a my logo on the left side. Ultimately what I am trying to accomplish is to fill the right side with text. I tried padding and sizing the font using "em" and/or "vw" but that doesn't work out too well (I guess because it's based on the whole header size, which makes alignment difficult).

Current display:
[image]

Desired result:
[image]

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Hi omri_saadon - sorry for the delayed response. I am new to stack overflow and I thought I would get a notification when someone responded.

Here is my header.php:

Comment: Most of my header.php, stack overflow has a character limit....

<div id="site-header">
  <a href="tel:+1-619-722-0248""<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
   <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="">
  </a>
 <div class="site-header-text-container">
  <div class="site-header-text-1">
  PROFESSIONAL | CONVENIENT | AFFORDABLE
  </div>

 </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to create your desired result, you can float the first div inside of the header to the left  and the second div to right with css. Here is an example:

```
#div-with-logo {
        float:left;
        width:50%;
        }

#div-with-text {
        float:right;
        width:50%;
        }
```

Here is some more information on positioning divs with css http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Hi Explicit - I tried this out and it came close. I used the "inspect element" tool in Chrome and that lead me to knowing the banner is located in the .site-header div. So my header.php now looks like this:
<div id="site-header">
  <a href="tel:+1-619-722-0248""<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
   <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="">
  </a>
  <div class="site-header-text-1">
  PROFESSIONAL | CONVENIENT | AFFORDABLE
  </div> 
</div>

Comment: I also added the suggestion you gave to style.css:
.site-header{
float:left;
width:50%;
}

.site-header-text-1 {
float: right;
width:50%;
color: #E1D507;
font-family: "Engravers MT";
}

I've taken my website off maintenance mode so you can check it out if that helps:
www.sourcecodedynamics.com

Comment: It seems that I can only float a div above or below the image, depending on if I put the text div above or within the header div respectively.

Comment: ok 3 options for you to deal with this. The reason things aren't floating right for you is because you're using a banner image that's the full width of the page. If you want those to work, you would need to cut out just the part with the logo and give the div a background color. Option 2 would be to use absolute positioning of elements on top of your banner image. Option 3 would be to put everything into 1 image and map the links on the image like this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_usemap.asp. Option 1 is the best though.

Comment: Hi Explicit - I think option 3 would work out best for me if I could assign % values instead of exact coordinates. I need to make the coords responsive so they are relative to the device viewing it. Is that possible?

Comment: To give some reason to why I think option 3... I tried option one and realized floating the site-header div is affecting the navigation menu (not sure why, it's not within that div). option 2 is what I was doing in the first place, which came close, but I couldn't get the font to be responsive (the positioning of the div wasn't % based and wouldn't always appear in the same place, depending on the window size).

Comment: More on option 1; I tried only floating the site-header-text div which corrected the issue of the affecting the navigation menu, but when I viewed the site on my phone the div didn't appear at all.

Comment: You can use this jquery plugin to make the imagemap responsive http://mattstow.com/experiment/responsive-image-maps/rwd-image-maps.html Using option 1, If you specify image and div widths with a %, I'm guessing that should solve your issue with the missing div. The div is there, it's probably just hiding.

Comment: Wow, that is fantastic! I spent a bunch of time trying to figure out what to do with the plugin before I realized it just worked without any further configuration lol.

Your suggestion of using an imagemap paired with that plugin is perfect. Thanks a ton, this is working perfectly.

It may be helpful to other to use this site for creating and finding the coords of the imagemap:
http://www.mobilefish.com/services/image_map/image_map.php